# Java Matcher search and replace only some hits

Tags: java, search, replace, conditional-statements

I am doing a standard search and replace loop in Java using Matcher, find, appendReplacement, and appendTail.  My issue is that I have an additional condition which must be true to determine if I should actually do the replacement or to leave the string intact at a particular match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Some Regex");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Some buffer of text which needs some replacements.");

StringBuffer updatedBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
  if (someCondition) {
    m.appendReplacement(updatedBuffer, "Some Replacement");
  }
  else {
    // leave the text unchanged at this point.
    // is there something equivalent to: m.appendOriginal(updatedBuffer)
  }
}
m.appendTail(updatedBuffer);
```

I can compute this by holding onto the end() of the last match using the end() of this match and pulling from the original string, but figured there might be a more intended way to do this.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question might be more suited for the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site. They can critique your code and offer suggestions for improving it. Questions for stack overflow should have some sort of reproducible problem in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuffer updatedBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(updatedBuffer,
            someCondition ? "Some Replacement" : m.group());
}
m.appendTail(updatedBuffer);
```

Or

```
return Pattern.compile("Some Regex")
    .matcher("Some buffer of text which needs some replacements.")
    .replaceAll(mr -> condition ? "Some Replacement" : mr.group());
```

where mr is a MatchResult similar to matcher methods.

Comment: Thank you Joop. I had always used group(int) to reference matched parenthetical submatches, and hadn't noticed the group(void) overload for the entire match. Most appreciated!

Comment: Joop, yet another regex gem I probably should have known.  Thank you, again!